# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] returns empty PHP

Tags: php, http-referer

Basically I have 2 websites. **website1** is the main website which is a blog. Now I am sending visitors to **website2** if the visitor is not logged in to **website1**. Then **website2** redirects visitors back to the **website1** with some data so that he can log in.

Now my goal is to check if the user is coming from **website2** or not.

I tried

`$referer_parse = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
 var_dump($referer_parse);`

which returns `array(1) { ["path"]=> string(0) "" }`

I created an **anchor tag** for **website1** and the visitors coming to **website1** by clicking on the link shows the right things for the above code. But it is not working when **website2** redirects automatically.

Comment: I would use manually set UTM parameters like `http://www.website-a.com/?utm_source=website-b`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I already have a secured parameter like this. But I want to prevent users from tryping the url themselves by checking this so it becomes more secured.

Comment: Keep one thing in mind. There is nothing like "a little bit secure". It's either 100% secure or not.